# How do I query both sides of a HABTM relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models - `Question & Tag`.

Both have a HABTM association between themselves. There is also a `questions_tags` join table.

If I have a question (`q`), I can find the tags by simply doing `q.tags`.

But, if I have a tag (`t`), when I try to go the other way (`t.questions`), I get an error like this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `questions' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fda147522b8>
```

Is HABTM not supposed to work both ways? How do I get the `questions` associated with a tag in my case?

Comment: can you show your code where you use `t.questions`. I doubt that t is not a Tag but an AR::Relation as the error suggest.  something like `t = Tag.where(id: some_id)` (forgot to add `.first`) which will cause the error

Comment: Ahhh.....you are right. It was returning an array....not the individual object. If you add that as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that t is not a `Tag` object but an AR::Relation as the error suggest. Something like `t = Tag.where(id: some_id)` (forgot to add .first) which will cause the error. :)